# Using codeigniter 3.14 not allowing me to use codeigniter session with ajax call

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have tried so many things but still facing the same issue. The application works fine in my localhost but in production it's not allowing me to use session with Ajax

Loaded session in autoload,
Done all setting's,
Also tried with database session and file based session.

Only creating issue while I'm using session values either with Ajax call or after creating session on Ajax call

Any suggestions what should I do?

```
function print_user(user) {
user.providerData.forEach(function(profile) {
    $.post("http://domain/connection/user_authentic", {
            Provider: profile.providerId,
            ProviderUID: profile.uid,
            Name: profile.displayName,
            Email: profile.email,
            PhotoURL: profile.photoURL,
        },
        function(data, status) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data)
            if (result.isUserLogged) {


                //window.location.reload();
                redirectUser('home?msg=welcome');

                console.log("Status: " + result.ProfileCompleted);
                console.log("Status: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("Redirect your User to Home");

            } else {
                console.log("Not allowed");
            }
        });
});
```

}

```
function redirectUser(uri) {
var base_url = "";
window.location.href = base_url + uri;
```

}

on controller side i'm simply fetching data and creating session and returning session data

Comment: What issue are you facing? are you using relative path on your ajax calls or full path? please give an example of one of your ajax calls that is not working.

Comment: @BrianRamsey - yes i'm using the complete URL path in ajax, i have edited my code please check, i'm getting user details thorugh firebase google sign in and then creating an ajax call to post data to my controller and on behalf of it creating User session but while success and reloading of page the session is still blank.

i have checked with my db and session has been created but current running app is not detecting that created session by ajax call

Comment: Codeigniter retains its session key in a cookie, you will need to get it and set the cookie yourself in JavaScript otherwise no authentication can occur

Comment: Thanks for your response but can you give me an example with Ajax call on behalf of my scenario

Comment: Can you confirm: 1) What the `cookie_path` is set in your config.php file - I find site wide / fixes it 2) Where your redirect user function is sending the user? Base_url looks blank which might end up in domain/controller/action/home which would not be correct.

Comment: Cookie_path is same as domain name ".Domain.com"and base_url is already defined in JavaScript variable I forgot to mention here